# Power Dissipation in an AC Circuit

Tags: power, ac, passive-networks, homework

I'm seeking clarification on power dissipation in an AC circuit with a specific scenario in mind.

I was able to calculate the RMS current through the AC Mains = √10 A

Considering that the upper parallel combination and lower one have phase difference π/4 and -π/4 respectively, can we directly calculate the power dissipated using Vᵣₘₛ*Iᵣₘₛ directly?

The AC source has an RMS Voltage of 200V, ω = 50 rad/s

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I won't supply complete solutions to homework questions, just hints that hopefully help the OP to solve the rest themselves)

I see two possible approaches:

- If you know voltage across some path, current through that path, and phase difference between voltage and current, then \$P = V_{rms} \cdot I_{rms} \cdot \cos\varphi \$
- Ideal capacitors and inductors don't dissipate power, only the resistors in your circuit do. So, if you know the current through a resistor, then \$P = {I_{rms}}^2 \cdot R \$

Comment: In the second method mentioned (P=Irms2⋅R), would we consider the phase difference between the current and impedance? If not, why?

Comment: If you treat an impedance as a value with a phase, then you get P = I² Z cosφ. For a resistor, φ=0, for a capacitor or inductor, φ=+/-90°. There is no such thing as a phase difference between an AC current and an impedance. The current is a sine wave over time, the impedance has no time dependance. You can have phase differences between two sine waves, e.g. an AC current and an AC voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You should work out the complex impedance of the capacitor+resistor pair and the inductor+resistor pair at the frequency in question.

Dividing the voltage by the two impedances will give you two complex currents.  The magnitude of the two complex currents can be used with the two resistor values and \$I^2R\$ to work out the power dissipated.

Alternatively you could add the two complex currents, then multiple the real part of the result by the voltage to give you the power.

Both approaches will give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct and they are how a real engineer should approach the problem. Textbooks like to use problems that can be solved without a calculator. So, here is the shortcut.

If the phase between the R and C/L in each leg is \$\pi/4 \$ or \$ 45^o \$, then

\$X_C = R1, X_L = R2  \$

and the impedance for each leg is:

\$Z = \sqrt{2} R\$

\$I_{rms} = \frac{V_{rms}}{Z}=\frac{200}{\sqrt{2} R} = \frac{100\sqrt{2}}{ R}\$

The power in the resistor is:

\$P_R = I^2 R = \left( \frac{100\sqrt{2}}{ R}\right)^{2} R = \frac{20000}{R}\$

Be sure to use RMS voltage for the source, then the current will be RMS and you get the proper power. The SE simulator uses peak voltage for the voltage source parameter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfBFe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's first derive a general formula for the active power:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{P}&=\text{V}_\text{RMS}\text{I}_\text{RMS}\cos\left(\varphi\right)\\
\\
&=\text{V}_\text{RMS}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{RMS}}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}\right|}\cdot\cos\left(\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{RMS}^2}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}\right|}\cdot\cos\left(\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}\right)\right)
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

For your circuit we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\text{Z}}&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(100+\frac{1}{\text{j}\cdot50\cdot200\cdot10^{-6}}\right)\left(50+1000\cdot10^{-3}\cdot50\text{j}\right)}{\displaystyle100+\frac{1}{\text{j}\cdot50\cdot200\cdot10^{-6}}+50+1000\cdot10^{-3}\cdot50\text{j}}\\
\\
&=60+20\text{j}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

So, we get:

$$\text{P}=\frac{200^2}{\sqrt{60^2+20^2}}\cdot\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{20}{60}\right)\right)=600\space\text{W}\tag3$$